# Poisson cumulative probability function in python returns a close but not true value! Why?

Tags: python, poisson

I am relatively new to python and am teaching myself. I came up with a challenge to improve my skill; to write a Poisson probability calculator.

I wrote 3 functions in total. 1st: Poisson probability of a single discrete variable. 2nd: Cumulative Poisson probability from 0. 3rd: Cumulative Poisson probability in a closed interval.

Somehow the first two functions work perfectly but the last, (which calls the 2nd), is very close but not true.

I used the following math:

Poisson distribution:

[image]

Cumulative Poisson distribution:

[image]

Interval Probability:

[image]

And here's my source code:

```
    from math import exp, factorial


def poissonpdf(mean, discvar):
    """Returns Poisson probability based on mean and a discreet random variable.

    :param mean: float
    :param discvar: positive integer or 0
    :return:  float between 0 and 1
    """
    usage = 'Usage: poisson(mean, discreet random variable)'

    # if type(discvar) != int or discvar < 0:
    #     print 'ERR: discreet random variable value invalid.'
    #     print usage
    #     return None

    # if type(mean) != int or float:
    #     print 'ERR: mean value invalid.'
    #     print usage
    #     return None

    probability = (mean**discvar * exp(-mean)) / float(factorial(discvar))
    return probability


def poissoncdf(mean, k):
    """Returns cumulative Poisson probability until k.

    :param mean: float
    :param k: integer
    :return: float between 0 and 1
    """
    cumulative = 0.0
    i = 0
    while i <= k:
        cumulative += (mean ** i) / float(factorial(i))
        i += 1
    cumulative *= exp(-mean)
    return cumulative


def poissoncdfinterval(mean, lower, upper):
    """Returns cumulative Poisson probability based on mean and a range of discreet random variables.

    Including lower bound and excluding upper.

    :param mean: float
    :param lower: positive integer or 0
    :param upper: positive integer or 0
    :return: float between 0 and 1
    """
    usage = 'Usage: poisson(mean, discreet random variable, number of iterations)'

    # if type(mean) != float or type(mean) != int:
    #     print 'ERR: mean value invalid.'
    #     print usage
    #     return None

    # if type(lower) != int or lower < 0 or type(upper) != int or upper < 0:
    #     print 'ERR: invalid interval.'
    #     print usage
    #     return None

    probability = poissoncdf(mean, upper) - poissoncdf(mean, lower)

    return probability

print 'PoissonPdf mean=4, X=2:', poissonpdf(4, 2) #works
print
print 'PoisoonCdf mean=4, from 0 to 2:', poissoncdf(4, 2) #works
print
print 'PosiionCdf on interval from 2,4 with mean 4:', poissoncdfinterval(4, 2, 4) #close...
```

I know that the third function does not include the upper bound.

Any correction in my PEP usage and any way of improving my syntax are welcome.

Comment: How "very close" are we talking here?

Comment: running the third function poissoncdfinterval(4, 2, 4) returns this:
0.390733629626
Where the actual value of it should be:
0.341892...

Comment: What makes you think that the actual value should be 0.341892? If you add the Poisson weight for `i=3` and `i=4` (which are the only two contributions to `poissoncdfinterval(4,2,4)`), you get `0.39073362962632913` with floats, `0.3907336296263291795993177870` using `Decimal`.

Comment: I used my calculator's Poisson function to check. IT nspire cx poissCdf(4,2,3) (as it includes the upper bound too I have it set to 3 not 4)

Comment: *Your* version includes the upper bound. Don't use an unreliable source for checking your correct result. What makes you think the above number is wrong? Did you check elsewhere? Ask wolfram alpha or something?

Comment: Yes of course! I loose the lower bound when doing this

    probability = poissoncdf(mean, upper) - poissoncdf(mean, lower)

not the upper. I'll check again right now.

Edit: Got it! Sorry took me a while. Thanks for making me realise my mistake.

Comment: How do you use handle the function for higher values? For higher values of k, it returns math overflow error. Any way to overcome it or any threshold that we can apply after which if will return 1?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my function was correct. I didn't realise that I was including the upper bound and excluding the lower and not the other way around.

I've changed this line:

```
probability = poissoncdf(mean, upper) - poissoncdf(mean, lower)
```

To this:

```
probability = poissoncdf(mean, upper) - poissoncdf(mean, (lower-1))
```

and now both bound should be included.

Yup, that's it.